# Alterar dados em DB4O em C#

Tags: c#, db4o

Como fazer para alterar um dado de uma "tabela" criada em Db4o?

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte objeto gravado em DB4O:

```
Nome = Emerson
Senha = Teste
```

Eu quero alterar somente o dado da Senha por exemplo de "Teste" para "NovoTeste", como posso conseguir alterar isso sem precisar fazer copiar o dado e regravar novamente?

Comment: Tô tentando fazer o download do banco, mas não estou conseguindo. Aliás, nem sei se o projeto existe mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para atualizar um objeto com o db4o, é necessário primeiramente recuperar ele do banco, para então alterá-lo e salvá-lo, com `db4oContainer.Store(entity)` . Não há como atualizar um objeto sem recuperá-lo do banco de dados antes.

**Alerta** : como o Cigano mencionou, creio que o projeto esteja abandonado - o site oficial e de documentação não estão mais no ar, eu mesmo usei o CHM (help compilado) nas últimas vezes que precisei consultar a documentação.

Comment: Obrigado, eu estava tentando com o Commit, por isso que não funcionava.